# How to obtain current user metadata in Clojure Friend?

Tags: clojure

I am using [Friend](https://github.com/cemerick/friend) library. I need to provide a request handler that will return user roles (and possibly some other metadata) for currently logged in user.

I've added a simple request handler:

```
  (GET "/userInfo.do" request
      (friend/identity request))
```

But this basically returns `nil`.
What is the proper way of fetching user session data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked:

```
  (GET "/userInfo.do" request
      (json/write-str (friend/current-authentication)))
```